# Issues with calling uber-api products with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, uber-api

I am trying to test out the uber-api products rest endpoint and can't get a successful response using angular. If I paste the $http.get url in the browser it works. However I always get an error response through angularjs. The jsfiddle below is a stripped example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

http://jsfiddle.net/t3kcwc7y/630/

```
function UberCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823&server_token=<token_here>')
  .success(function(data) {
      console.log('success');
      $scope.uberData = data;
  })
  .error(function(data) {
      console.log('error');
      $scope.uberData = 'Error: ' + data;
  });
}
```

I was unable to find a existing jsfiddle/plunker example so sorry if this has already been covered. Thanks in advance.

Some side notes, when testing in chrome I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" which appears to be chrome specific CORS error. It works in firefox. My ultimate goal is to execute this from salesforce/force.com and support on any browser. I'm not sure if the CORS error is due to jsfiddle or not.

Comment: After trying to work out CORS configuration on both the UBER side and the angular side. I moved the call instead from a browser javascript call to a server http callout and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the example for using the Uber API from the browser with CORS support:

https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api-reference

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token YOUR_SERVER_TOKEN");
xhr.send();
```